# Can not ping compute engine VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In the compute engine page GCP prompted me to save $12/month by reducing the size of my VM.  After selecting this option and reducing the size of my VM, I am unable to ping the external IP of the VM from external addresses. Also no web traffic. traceroute ends, does not reach the server.

Firewall rules are correct and in place to allow ICMP/HTTPS/HTTP.  Also when I test various networking scenario from the compute engine is says they should work and should pass firewall rules (I.e., it says a ping from my home PC should work, but it does not). I am able to PING/traceroute to external IP addresses from the compute engine VM.

I've tried several reboots.

Comment: Please update your question with  GCP Firewall configuration rules. Are you able to SSH into the GCE VM after resizing?

Comment: Issue was that after resizing my ip changed and I didn't realise. This can be closed.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. I posted an answer with a few more details that explains this situation and could be useful for community members.

Answer (score 2):

I posted this answer to make this issue and a way to avoid it more visible.

As it was confirmed at the comment section by *GaryB*, this issue was caused by IP changes after resizing the VM instance.

You can find more information about this behavior at the documentation [Ephemeral external IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#ephemeraladdress):

> An ephemeral external IP address is an IP address that does not
> persist beyond the life of the resource. When you create an instance
> or forwarding rule without specifying an IP address, the resource is
> automatically assigned an ephemeral external IP address.

and

> For VM instances, **the ephemeral external IP address is also released
> if you stop the instance**. **After you restart the instance, it is
> assigned a new ephemeral external IP address**.

**To avoid such situation**, you can follow the documentation [Reserving a static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address):

> If a virtual machine (VM) instance requires a fixed external IP
> address that does not change, you can obtain a static external IP
> address for that instance by using one of the following options:
>
> - [Reserve a new static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static) and then [assign the address to a new VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#assign_new_instance).
> - [Promote an existing ephemeral external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#promote_ephemeral_ip) to become a static external IP address.